# Efficient query involving count in subquery

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-5

Say I have this hypothetical many-to-many relationship:

```
public class Paper
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Author> Authors { get; set; }
}

public class Author
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Paper> Papers { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use LINQ to build a query that will give me the "popularity" of each author compared to other authors, which is the number of papers the author contributed to divided by the total number of author contributions in general across all papers. I've come up with a couple queries to achieve this.

Option 1:

```
var query1 = from author in db.Authors
             let sum = (double)db.Authors.Sum(a => a.Papers.Count)
             select new
             {
               Author = author,
               Popularity = author.Papers.Count / sum
             };
```

Option 2:

```
var temp = db.Authors.Select(a => new
           {
             Auth = a,
             Contribs = a.Papers.Count
           });
var query2 = temp.Select(a => new
             {
               Author = a,
               Popularity = a.Contribs / (double)temp.Sum(a2 => a2.Contribs)
             });
```

Basically, my question is this: which of these is more efficient, and are there other single queries that are more efficient? How do any of those compare to two separate queries, like this:

```
double sum = db.Authors.Sum(a => a.Papers.Count);
var query3 = from author in db.Authors
             select new
             {
               Author = author,
               Popularity = author.Papers.Count / sum
             };
```

Comment: Have you looked at what each of your approaches does at the database level? That's going to be the most important aspect. Once you know what SQL is issued - and once you've looked at the query plans for that SQL - you'll be in a much better position.

Comment: You have once more option: join grouping and count papers in groups. To choise what would the best you need to profile output sql's as Jon Skeet says.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, you can try them out yourself and see which one takes the longest for instance.

The first thing you should look for is that they translate perfectly into SQL or as close as possible so that the data doesn't get all get loaded in memory just to apply those computations.

But i feel that option 2 might be your best shot ,with one more optimization to cache the total sum of pages contributed. This way you only make one call to the db to get the authors which you anyway need, the rest will run in your code and there you can paralellize and do whatever you need to make it fast.

So something like this (sorry, I prefer the Fluent style of writing Linq):

```
//here you can even load only the needed info if you don't need the whole entity.
//I imagine you might only need the name and the Pages.Count which you can use below, this would be another optimization.
var allAuthors = db.Authors.All(); 

var totalPageCount = allAuthors.Sum(x => x.Pages.Count);

var theEndResult = allAuthors .Select(a => new
         {
           Author = a,
           Popularity = a.Pages.Count/ (double)totalPageCount
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 and 2 should generate the same SQL code. For readability I would go with **option 1**.
Option 3 will generate two SQL statements and be a little slower.